# Hide HTML Form Select on Print

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am using DataTables on a HTML table and would like to hide all select and inputs from the table headings.

I have used this code:

```
@media print{
    th select{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

But that didn't work.

One example is, in 1 column I have this as the heading:

```
<th>
    All Businesses
        <select name='business' id='business'>
        <option value=''>All Businesses...</option>
        <option value='Business 1'>Business 1</option>
        <option value='Business 2'>Business 2</option>
        <option value='Business 3'>Business 3</option>
    </select>
</th>
```

Which when printing looks like this:

[image: Image of Headings]

Ideally I need a solution that means the select isn't in the TH but is in the same position as it is now (just under the "All Businesses" bit). I say this because DataTables has a visibility column which ends up using everything in the `th` meaning the business names show up in that as well.

Thanks!

This is the full code for the table head:

```
$label_to_name = array();

    $tableRes = $db->query("SELECT * from staff_fields");
    $table = "<table class='table' id='table'><thead><tr><th>All Businesses<select name='business' id='business'><option value=''>All Businesses...</option><option value='Business 1'>Business 1</option><option value='Business 2'>Business 2</option><option value='Business 3'>Business 3</option></select></th>";
    $trowss = $tableRes->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $js = "";
    $i = 1;

    foreach($trowss as $trows){

        if($trows['type'] == "yesno"){
            $search_option = "<select id='".$trows['name']."' name='".$trows['name']."'><option value=''>Select Filter...<option value='Yes'>Yes</option><option value='No'>No</option></select>";

            $js .= "var ".$trows['name']."index = ".$i.";

    $('#".$trows['name']."').on('change',function(){
        oTable.columns(".$trows['name']."index).search($(this).val()).draw();
    });


    ";


        }else{
            $search_option = "<input type='text' name='".$trows['name']."' id='".$trows['name']."' placeholder='Type to Search...'>";

            $js .=  "var ".$trows['name']."index = ".$i.";
    $('#".$trows['name']."').on('input',function(){
        oTable.columns(".$trows['name']."index).search($(this).val()).draw();
    });

    ";


        }

        $table .= "<div class='table_heading'><th>".$trows['label']."</th>".$search_option."</div>";
        $label_to_name[$trows['label']] = $trows['name'];

        $i++;


    }
    $table .= "</tr></thead><tbody>";
```

HTML Output:

```
<table class='table' id='table'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            All Businesses
            <select name='business' id='business'>
                <option value=''>All Businesses...</option>
                <option value='Business 1'>Business 1</option>
                <option value='Business 2'>Business 2</option>
                <option value='Business 3'>Business 3</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>First Name<input type='text' name='first_name1459057776924' id='first_name1459057776924' placeholder='Type to Search...'></th>
        <th>Last Name<input type='text' name='last_name1459057788088' id='last_name1459057788088' placeholder='Type to Search...'></th>
        <th>Job Title<input type='text' name='job_title1459057796608' id='job_title1459057796608' placeholder='Type to Search...'></th>
        <th>
            Proof of Age on File
            <select id='proof_of_age_on_file1459057805910' name='proof_of_age_on_file1459057805910'>
                <option value=''>Select Filter...
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                <option value='No'>No</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>Date of Birth<input type='text' name='date_of_birth1459057814082' id='date_of_birth1459057814082' placeholder='Type to Search...'></th>
        <th>Start Date<input type='text' name='start_date1459057824504' id='start_date1459057824504' placeholder='Type to Search...'></th>
        <th>
            Signed Contract in Place
            <select id='signed_contract_in_place1459057835607' name='signed_contract_in_place1459057835607'>
                <option value=''>Select Filter...
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                <option value='No'>No</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>
            DBS on File
            <select id='dbs_on_file1459057844504' name='dbs_on_file1459057844504'>
                <option value=''>Select Filter...
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                <option value='No'>No</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>DBS Date<input type='text' name='dbs_date1459057856098' id='dbs_date1459057856098' placeholder='Type to Search...'></th>
        <th>
            References Received
            <select id='references_received1459057869650' name='references_received1459057869650'>
                <option value=''>Select Filter...
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                <option value='No'>No</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>
            Payroll Info Given to HO
            <select id='payroll_information_given_to_ho1459057881692' name='payroll_information_given_to_ho1459057881692'>
                <option value=''>Select Filter...
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                <option value='No'>No</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>Leaving Date<input type='text' name='leaving_date1459057889857' id='leaving_date1459057889857' placeholder='Type to Search...'></th>
        <th>
            Left
            <select id='left1459263499753' name='left1459263499753'>
                <option value=''>Select Filter...
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                <option value='No'>No</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>Next Of Kin (Name, Relationship and Contact Number)<input type='text' name='next_of_kin1459342113034' id='next_of_kin1459342113034' placeholder='Type to Search...'></th>
        <th>Medical Condition<input type='text' name='medical_condition1459342141909' id='medical_condition1459342141909' placeholder='Type to Search...'></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is not with your css, but with your HTML.

You should make sure that your `<th>` tag is inside a `<table> <tr>` tag, otherwise the browser will change your structure and the `@media print` will not apply.

You can always check that your html structure is valid using the [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @media print {
                th select {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    All Businesses
                    <select name='business' id='business'>
                        <option value=''>All Businesses...</option>
                        <option value='Business 1'>Business 1</option>
                        <option value='Business 2'>Business 2</option>
                        <option value='Business 3'>Business 3</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can confirm I have the <tr> tags. I will update my post with the code.

Comment: Update your question with the complete HTML code that you have, after everything was rendered.

Comment: The code in my example seems to work just fine. If you also want to hide the `<input>` elements you should have them inside your css as well (currently your css only applies to `th select`, but not to `th input`)

Comment: Check the image I posted in my question, the select values are still showing?

Comment: I have done some checking and the CSS should be working but it still shows the select on the print.

Comment: There are several options here: 1. You have some javascript code that runs and changes the HTML (so we need to see that html after that change). 2. You don't load the CSS correctly. Is it possible to link to a page where we can see that problem happen (full page with html/css/etc)? you can use http://jsfiddle.net for that.

Comment: Seems the problem is with datatables not obeying @media print rules... is there a way for me to display the table like it is but with the select and inputs not part of the TH?

Comment: I don't think that datatables is not obeying @media print rules (unless they have their own css with HIGHER priority), more likely the HTML is not the one you gave (because datatables changed it). This is why I asked for a complete working page.

Comment: Need to use the datatables print button so it prints just the table and not the entire page.

Comment: There is no print button in your example. Obviously that print button CHANGES the html, which makes your CSS code not relevant anymore. Give an example with the correct html.

Comment: There is but it is showing as a normal span text (check the top left)